# Package lipsum, babel (french) and active characters

Tags: lipsum, babel-french

In the following document, the two paragraphs should be composed in the same way. But the spacing before 'high punctuation' characters (`;`) is not correct in the paragraph created by the `\lipsum` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lipsum-babel-test.ltd.tex}
\ProvidesFile{test.ltd.tex}

\NewLipsumPar{Pour moi, je n'ai jamais présumé que mon esprit fût en
  rien plus parfait que ceux du commun; même j'ai souvent souhaité
  d'avoir la pensée aussi prompte, ou l'imagination aussi nette et
  distincte ou la mémoire aussi ample ou aussi présente, que quelques
  autres. Et je ne sache point de qualités que celles-ci qui servent à
  la perfection de l'esprit; car pour la raison, ou le sens, d'autant
  qu'elle est la seule chose qui nous rend hommes et nous distingue des
  bêtes, je veux croire qu'elle est tout entière en un chacun; et suivre
  en ceci l'opinion commune des philosophes, qui disent qu'il n'y a du
  plus et du moins qu'entre les accidents, et non point entre les formes
  ou natures des individus d'une même espèce.}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\SetLipsumText{lipsum-babel-test}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

Pour moi, je n'ai jamais présumé que mon esprit fût en rien plus parfait
que ceux du commun; même j'ai souvent souhaité d'avoir la pensée aussi
prompte, ou l'imagination aussi nette et distincte ou la mémoire aussi
ample ou aussi présente, que quelques autres. Et je ne sache point de
qualités que celles-ci qui servent à la perfection de l'esprit; car pour
la raison, ou le sens, d'autant qu'elle est la seule chose qui nous rend
hommes et nous distingue des bêtes, je veux croire qu'elle est tout
entière en un chacun; et suivre en ceci l'opinion commune des
philosophes, qui disent qu'il n'y a du plus et du moins qu'entre les
accidents, et non point entre les formes ou natures des individus d'une
même espèce.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Without trying, I'd say you need `\SetLipsumText{lipsum-babel-test}` *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: `babel` makes `;` an active character only at the `\begin{document}`, so before that the `;` is only a `;`. Move the `\SetLipsumText{lipsum-babel-test}` after `\begin{document}` (as egreg just said :)

Comment: @egreg  Thank you for your quick and relevant answer.